# Density Function Transformation Probelm

Tags: probability, density-function

I'm having trouble with this question, the $P(Y \ge y)$ part of the equation is confusing me since its not the cdf and I'm not sure how I should proceed.

Suppose X has density function $x/2$  for $0 < x < 2$ and 0 otherwise. Find the density function of $Y= X(2-X)$ by computing $P(Y \ge y)$ and then differentiating.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Note for any $y\in (0,1)$, $(Y\geq y)=(1-\sqrt{1-y}\leq X\leq 1+\sqrt{1-y})$. Hence $P(Y\geq y)=P(1-\sqrt{1-y}\leq X\leq 1+\sqrt{1-y})=\sqrt{1-y}.$ Therefore, $$f_Y(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}&\mathrm{if}\,\,0<y<1\\0&\mathrm{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Thanks, but how does the P(Y>y) = the square root of 1-y?

Comment: @John I think he solved this X(2-X)>=y , which is just finding roots of the following inequality x^2-2x+y<=0 and he obtained that 1-sqrt(1-y)<=X<=1+sqrt(1-y).

Comment: I might be over thinking it now but isn't P(Y<=y) = sqrt(1-y) which makes P(Y>=y) = 1-sqrt(1-y) ? I got the answer but to get the density of Y we differentiate the cdf of Y, but in this question it tells you to calculate the opposite of a cdf [ P(Y>=y) ] and then to differentiate it, how does that give the pdf.